# Equilibrium point variable with time

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, fixed-points

I have a dynamical system $dx/dt=f(a,b,c,d, x,t)$, where $x=(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ and $a,b,c,d$ are parameters.

I put $dx/dt=0$ in order to calculate equilibrium points and get a variable-time point $\overline{x}(t)=(\overline{x_1}(t),\overline{x_2}(t),\overline{x_3}(t))$ s.t. $d\overline{x}/dt=0$.

This occurs because the parameters $a,b,c,d$ are involved with $t$.

How can I apply this? I mean, what can I conclude? For each $t$, I have a different equilibrium point!

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Perhaps you guessed correctly that you conclude nothing from knowing those points. In particular, they need not be solutions. That's not a good approach when you have a dependence on time.

Comment: @JohnB, really. Thank you so much. Do you know another approach when this situation occur? Many thanks!

Comment: Yes, lots of other approaches, but your question is too general since it depends substantially on the right-hand side. Sorry, either you tells more about the right-hand or nothing helpful can be said.

Comment: I understand, thank you very much.